# SSIS Importing a column from excel after searching for occurrence of a string in it

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am looking for a way in SSIS to scan the contents of all columns in Excel for a string and if it matches the string I am looking for, then to import that column into a table in SQL Server.

One catch is that the headers in the Excel file are three rows down (i.e.) Row 4 has the headers. The first three are just blanks. So is there also a way to skip these lines and then scan the 4th row for the string and then determine the column and import that column into SQL Server?

Is this possible in SSIS?

Thank you in advance for your help and time.

Comment: As a wise man once said (and I often repeat), you can do pretty much anything with a script task.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which version of SSIS but depending on the version you can use a script task with either C# or VB.net.

I would use something like this code to find the correct string:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

object False = false;
object True = true;

_Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks._Open(@"C:\tmp\StackOverflow.xlsx",False, False,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,False,False,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,False,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,True);

_Worksheet ws = (_Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

string from = "A1";
string to = END OF YOUR EXCEL DOCUMENT;

Range rng = ws.get_Range(from,to);

Range findRng = rng.Find("YOUR STRING",Missing.Value,XlFindLookIn.xlValues,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,XlSearchDirection.xlNext,False,False,Missing.Value);
```

More info can be found here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302096